# an exercise in 'Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning'

Tags: machine-learning, harmonic-functions, pattern-recognition

I am trying to solve problem 3.14 in Pattern Recognition and Machine Leanring, [exercise figure here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jllE.png). Can anyone help?

Comment: What have you tried?  Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: I have not got a single clue about how to solve it :-)